# Add text at the end of document fragments on a Mac

Tags: macos, replace, terminal, find

On a Mac, I have a directory of html files that are all document fragments. Using the TexFinderX app, I was easily able to do a find/replace and add everything at the top of the documents that I wanted (i.e.  etc.) .

Now I need to find a way to add the closing tags to all of the documents (i.e.  ).  TexFinderX does not have a way to do this since the documents do not have anything in common at the end of the files.

Is there a Terminal command that can do this for all html files in a directory and it's subdirectories?

Thanks,
Linda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT:*

Well i was trying to keep it simple and avoid Bash scripting but it seems find doesnt allow for output redirection... so try this instead:

`for f in ~/html/*.html; do echo "Processing $f file.." && cat ~/close.html >> $f; done`

---

Put your closing tags in a file... well call it `close.html` and we'll jsut put it in your home directory `/Users/youruser/close.html`. Well assume your docs are in `/Users/youruser/html`

Open Terminal.app and do the following command:

```
find ~/html -type f -name "*.html" -exec cat ~/close.html >> {} \;
```

youll want to test that first... my `find` kung-fu is rusty